# Load and change Text font

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fonts

I created multiple buttons in unity from script,I can't use GUI.Button(for reasons),Now I try to change the default Font?

How can I load my custom Font that imports in assets folder?
I'm new to unity.Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

This is where I I have the font now and that's not working:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project, create a file named *Resources* in the *Assets* folder. Now, place the font there.

Let's say that the name of font is "yourFont".

It should be placed in here: `Assets/Resources/yourFont`

To load it:

```
public Text yourText;

void Start()
{
    //To load it:
    Font font = Resources.Load("yourFont") as Font;


    //To assign it to the Text component:
    yourText.font = font;
}
```

Comment: What is the technical jargon/lingo/term for when you use the keyword 'as', like in your case 'as Font' ?

Comment: @Chad `as` is an operator that converts a type to another type. You can call that "cast operation".

Comment: @Programmer i tried this, but font always return null :-(

Comment: Update your question with a screenshot is where you placed the font.

Comment: @R.T It is `Resources` **not** `Recources`. Fix that! Copy the folder name directly from here and paste it there. If you have further problems, please update your question with the latest screenshot again and also put the Code you are using in the question. Also, don't forget to drag the Text object to the yourText slot in your script.

Comment: @Programmer god!!! i made a really stupid mistake, Now i have a new Problem,i updated that. thank U so much for your help

Comment: Hi, you have a totally different problem now which is not related to your original problem. You can now load fonts. You can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this question now and ask a new question about why your persian font is not working. Make sure to include your code and the screenshot of where you placed the font. Finally, make sure to mention what you mean by "does not work". If people don't understand your problem, you won't get an answer. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Font myFont;
public Text text;

void Start()
{
    text.font = myFont;
}
```

Drag the font and the text object in the inspector.